# How do I cater for all iOS platforms using cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I want to use Cocos2D framework, but I want to know how to place an object once in code, and for it to appear in the correct position on all devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He want's to know how to make universal code for his game.

E.g. Place something dead center for all formats.

Cocos2d automatically fixes positioning for iPhone4.

It uses POINTS not PIXELS to place objects onto the screen, this is your first problem fixed.

For iPad, you need to do some work. I suggest reading this post.

http://michaelgilkes.info/cocos2d-using-hd-images-for-ipad-in-a-universal-app/

I found it helpful and a very good stepping stone to come to a conclusion that allowed me to create a universal application with very little additional code.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly have no idea what you're asking, but possibly you want to know the screen sizes. Here they are in pixels:

iPhone < 4: 320 x 480

iPhone >= 4: 640 x 960

iPad: 768 x 1024

Comment: Ha ha. + 1 for a funny answer to an impossible question. Wow.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. If I want to place an object on the screen, that takes up 10% of the screen area. It seems as though I can't specify it as a pixel value? Because 32x48 is 10% for Iphone 3, but would be like 5% for Iphone 4?

Comment: The `bounds` of the screen are what you're after. Those are 320x480 for iPhone and 768x1024 for iPad. This changes if you have a status bar (20 x width <- depends on orientation) or a navigationbar or tabbar (44 x width).

Comment: You guys aren't answering the question? I already know they have different sizes, that's stated in the question. How does one implement OpenGLES graphics solution which will cater to the variation in screen sizes, don't we have to explicitly set the pixel size of objects?

Comment: Wait, you asked a vague borderline incomprehensible question and you're upset we aren't answering it correctly?